# jQuery - Cannot parse json

Tags: jquery, python, json, flask

I'm sending a response through my Python server in json, using `json.dumps`

```
return '{"status":200, "response":%s}' % (json.dumps(data))
```

I'm retrieving it via jQuery, in the following fashion.

```
$.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type : "GET",
        url: url,
        data : {},
        success : function(result){
            alert(result)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR)
            alert(textStatus)
            alert(errorThrown)
        },
    });
```

The response that I get is

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "count": 2,
        "2015_03_16": [
            {
                "imei1": "111",
                "status": "Success",
                "imei2": "NA",
                "msisdn": "111",
                "offer_id": "1",
                "ctype": "pre",
                "date": "2015-03-16 06:42:46",
                "recharge_api": "12",
                "points": "2",
                "operator": "vodafone",
                "model": "MicromaxA069",
                "circle": "delhi"
            },
            {
                "imei1": "111",
                "status": "Success",
                "imei2": "NA",
                "msisdn": "111",
                "offer_id": "1",
                "ctype": "pre",
                "date": "2015-03-16 06:42:46",
                "recharge_api": "12",
                "points": "2",
                "operator": "vodafone",
                "model": "MicromaxA069",
                "circle": "delhi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

upon alerting the error, it shows `parserror`. I've read various post that the data needed to be send in json for jquery to parse it, and I've done the same. Why I'm still getting the error?

**EDIT**

I just created a dummy code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        Helo
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="untitled.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url: 'a.json',
            data : {},
            success : function(result){
                alert(result)
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR)
            },
        });
    });

    </script>
</html>
```

I created a file a.json in the same directory, having the following content.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "count": 3,
        "2015_03_16": [
            {
                "InstallCount": "1",
                "ad": "Amazon",
                "conversion": null,
                "ClickCount": "0"
            },
            {
                "InstallCount": "2",
                "ad": "Mobikwik",
                "conversion": "0.6667",
                "ClickCount": "3"
            },
            {
                "InstallCount": "1",
                "ad": "Quickr",
                "conversion": "1.0000",
                "ClickCount": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I ran the above HTML code, it still goes into the error function and logs the following result.

```
readyState 4
responseText "{"status":200, "response":{"count": 3, "2015_03_16": [{"InstallCount": "1", "ad": "Amazon", "conversion": null, "ClickCount": "0"}, {"InstallCount": "2", "ad": "Mobikwik", "conversion": "0.6667", "ClickCount": "3"}, {"InstallCount": "1", "ad": "Quickr", "conversion": "1.0000", "ClickCount": "1"}]}} "
status 200
statusText "OK"
abort function(a)
always function()
complete function()
done function()
error function()
fail function()
getAllResponseHeaders function()
getResponseHeader function(a)
overrideMimeType function(a)
pipe function()
progress function()
promise function(a)
setRequestHeader function(a, b)
state function()
statusCode function(a)
success function()
then function()
```

**Now what wrong am I doing** You can try the above code in your system as well.

Comment: You are not returning JSONP, you are returning JSON. You configured jQuery to look for the former.

Comment: Did you check the content body type and header?

Comment: on running the json response through [jsonlint.com], it seems that you are missing a square bracket `]` at the end...

Comment: $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type : "GET",
        url: url,
        data : {},
        success : function(result){
            alert(result)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR)
            alert(textStatus)
            alert(errorThrown)
        },
    });

Comment: Now upon alerting `alert(jqXHR),alert(textStatus),alert(errorThrown)` I get `object[object],error,''` respectively

Comment: @fijas: rather, there is an extra bracket at the front.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That was a typo.

Comment: @user1162512: nowhere in your code do you add those brackets, though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters- I've tried with adding/removing `[]` in my python code and thereby getting the response  back in json with/without `[]` respectively. Still no success. For current situation, ie as per current question, I've used `return '[{"status":200, "response":%s}]' % (json.dumps(data))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling jQuery to expect *JSON**P***, not JSON. JSONP is JSON wrapped in a callback, but you provided no such callback wrapper.

Remove the `p` from the `jsonp` type in the `$.ajax()` call, or add a callback wrapper. The callback name is found in the `callback` GET parameter.

You'll also need to return a proper JSON response with the right content type. Since you are using Flask the *easiest* way to do this is to use the [`jsonify()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify); it'll create a response object with the correct content type set for you:

```
from flask import jsonify

# ...

return jsonify(status=200, response=data)
```

The alternative would be to return the string you built but with a status code and header dictionary:

```
return '{"status":200, "response":%s}' % (json.dumps(data)), 200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

Either way, you can then use [the decorator from this Flask snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/79/) to *also* support JSONP. You'd put it after the `@app.route()` decorator, before your view function:

```
@app.route('/some/path')
@jsonp
def your_view_function():
    # ...
```

Comment: Upon alerting alert(jqXHR),alert(textStatus),alert(errorThrown) I get object[object],error,'' respectively

Comment: PS: I've used jsbeautify plugin in my chrome and I get correct response in my browser while hitting that url from address bar.

Comment: @user1162512: does the console show any more information about the parseerror?

Comment: What else info can I output? Please let me know

Comment: @user1162512: there are two questions here: why does your output in your browser show you have a `[..]` list wrapped around the object that your code doesn't have, and what headers and status code does your developer console network tab show for the AJAX request?

Comment: I did `console.log(jqXHR)`.  and the output I got is `readyState
 
 0
responseText
 
 ""
status
 
 0
statusText
 
 "error"
abort
 
 function(a)
always
 
 function()
complete
 
 function()
done
 
 function()
error
 
 function()
fail
 
 function()
getAllResponseHeaders
 
 function()
getResponseHeader
 
 function(a)
overrideMimeType
 
 function(a)
pipe
 
 function()
progress
 
 function()
promise
 
 function(a)
setRequestHeader
 
 function(a, b)
state
 
 function()
statusCode
 
 function(a)
success
 
 function()
then
 
 function()`

Comment: @user1162512: that seems to indicate you got an empty string as a response. But then again, if you typed that into the console without an actual request that's no help as it'll not reflect the current status of your erroring response at all.

Comment: Well, I tried a different version,still getting the same response. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @user1162512: I asked you for the headers before; what is the Content-Typye header on the response in both cases?

Comment: @user1162512: so what web framework are you using to return the response? You don't return HTML, you are returning JSON so you'll need to set the content type to reflect this.

Comment: I'm using Flask. and I return my response in the following way . `return '{"status":200, "response":%s}' % (json.dumps(data))`

Comment: Any suggestion please!!

Comment: thanks. I change the content-type ti `application/json`, but the response is "". However, I'm getting the response back when hitting that endpoint via browser address bar.

Comment: Its quite unusual. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @user1162512: so are you 100% certain your AJAX call is hitting the right URL? Is this using the same domain name or does it go across domains (at which point you have to use JSONP)? Is there nothing in the console that Chrome told you it refused to load the response for some reason?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Firebug was throwing a CORS error, which was blocking the request. I cors-enabled that view in Flask and it started working. THANKYOU VERY MUCH FOR THE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

server return error

you can find error with Chrome Developer Tools

open Developer Tools, click "Console"

res = [{"status":200, "response":{"count": 2, "2015_03_16": [{"imei1": "111", "status": "Success", "imei2": "NA", "msisdn": "111", "offer_id": "1", "ctype": "pre", "date": "2015-03-16 06:42:46", "recharge_api": "12", "points": "2", "operator": "vodafone", "model": "MicromaxA069", "circle": "delhi"}, {"imei1": "111", "status": "Success", "imei2": "NA", "msisdn": "111", "offer_id": "1", "ctype": "pre", "date": "2015-03-16 06:42:46", "recharge_api": "12", "points": "2", "operator": "vodafone", "model": "MicromaxA069", "circle": "delhi"}]}}

you will get error info : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

easy to find end of response need a "]"

and sorry for my poor english